# BTOOOM! Complete plot

Tags: resources, btooom

I recently watched the BTOOOM anime and thought to myself "Oh man, finally a decent anime". But then surprise. The final episode isn't the final of the story and leaves you hanging while you wait for season 2, which from what I've discovered won't be made. Bummer.

So I searched for the manga and found out that it has 26 volumes but because of licensing the final volume won't be published until some time end of 2019. At least how it shows up on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btooom!#Volume_list

I want to know how it ends and how the plot unfolds. Is there some place where I can find the plot of each episode?

Note that I'm not just interested in the ending (one or the other of the versions) but how the plot actually unfolds.

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can know of the ending and how the plot actually unfolds is to **read the rest of the chapters you haven't**. Since the final volume hasn't been translated and released yet, *you either need to buy up to the last translated volume and buy a raw version of the final volume and be able to read Japanese, or ask someone you know who knows Japanese to at least give you a rough idea of what happens*. I would not rely on the [wikia pages](https://btooom.fandom.com/wiki/Chapters) for this manga as they are not updated, which might mean that either contributors to the site only read scanlations or they haven't got the time to update yet.

So far, **I can't find sites similar to wikia that actually details what happens per chapter** so the only options you have are what I mentioned above. Unless, of course, someone here on the site actually follows the manga, understands Japanese and has read up to the final volume.

Comment: There's two different endings to the series, why and how it happens is a bit of a spoiler. But needless to say both left fans disappointed. AFAIR it's worth noting that the entirety has not been translated, officially or unofficially. Such post are basically soliciting spoilers because the material is otherwise unavailable to them in a language they can read.